# Как вызвать метод с модификатором доступа private вне класса, в котором находится этот метод?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть класс `Test`

```
import android.graphics.Region

class Test {
    private val mRegionInScreen = Region()

    private fun setRegionInScreen(region: Region) {
        mRegionInScreen.set(region)
    }
}
```

Мне нужно вызвать метод `setRegionInScreen` вне класса `Test`

Я пытался сделать это с помощью следующего кода

```
val test = Test()
val method = Test::class.java.getMethod("setRegionInScreen", Region::class.javaPrimitiveType)
method.invoke(test, Region(0, 0, 500, 500))
```

Но этот код выдает ошибку `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null`

Как мне вызвать метод `setRegionInScreen` вне класса `Test`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59370915/how-to-call-private-functions-of-a-class-from-outside-the-class-in-kotlin?rq=1

Comment: @RottenRat, там ответы по Kotlin reflection, автор же пытается использовать Java reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного по-другому надо.

```
val test = Test()
val method = Test::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("setRegionInScreen", Region::class.java)
method.isAccessible = true
method.invoke(test, Region(0, 0, 500, 500))
```

Метод `getMethod()` ищет только публичные методы.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object.